# Change one column of a DataFrame only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas with Python 3. I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns, but I only want to change the data type of all the values in one of the columns and leave the others alone. The only way I could find to accomplish this is to edit the column, remove the original column and then merge the edited one back. I would like to edit the column without having to remove and merge, leaving the the rest of the dataframe unaffected. Is this possible?

Here is my solution now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

def make_float(var):
    var = float(var)
    return var

#create a new dataframe with the value types I want
df2 = df1['column'].apply(make_float)
#remove the original column
df3 = df1.drop('column',1)
#merge the dataframes
df1 = pd.concat([df3,df2],axis=1)
```

It also doesn't work to apply the function to the dataframe directly. For example:

```
df1['column'].apply(make_float)
print(type(df1.iloc[1]['column']))
```

yields:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks to the help from Yakym I realized that this also would have worked: df1['column'] = df1['column'].apply(make_float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1['column'] = df1['column'].astype(float)
```

It will raise an error if conversion fails for some row.

Apply does not work inplace, but rather returns a series that you discard in this line:

```
df1['column'].apply(make_float)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Yakym's solution, you can also do this -

```
df['column'] += 0.0
```